# How to use (i in nums) with foreach in R?

Tags: r, foreach

How can I define something similar to `for(i in nums)` in case of `foreach`? It seems that `foreach` allows `i=1:nums`, but in my case numbers in `nums` are not sequential.

```
nums <- c(1,2,5,8)
prob <- foreach(i in nums, .combine = rbind, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar% {
  #...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't use `in` with `foreach()`. You just use named parameters. Try

```
nums <- c(1,2,5,8)
prob <- foreach(i =nums, .combine = rbind, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar% {#...}
```

The parameters will accept a vector without problem. The `1:n` syntax is just an easy way to create a vector of elements from 1 to n. But you can pass in your own vector directly.